# Improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}(1+\frac{1}{x})e^\frac{-1}{x}dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

How to evaluate this integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right) e^{-1/x}dx $$

Please help

Comment: Have you tried substituting $u=-1/x$ ?

Comment: Are you trying to decide if the improper integral *exists*? You don't need to calculate a value to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$u=-\frac1x$$
Then
$$x^2du=dx$$

So
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{\infty}^{1} \left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right) e^{-1/x}dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} (1-u)u^{-2}e^u du
\end{align}

This is easily calculated using integration by parts.

---

\begin{align}
\int u^{-2}e^u du &= -u^{-1}e^u - \int-u^{-1}e^u du \\
\int u^{-2}e^u du - \int u^{-1}e^u du &= -u^{-1}e^u \\
\int_{-\infty}^{-1} (1-u)u^{-2}e^u du &= \left[-u^{-1}e^u\right]_{-\infty}^{-1}\\
&=e^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: Not sure I see the integration by parts argument here. Also there appear to be issues with the bounds of your integrals.

Comment: @GrantB. my careless mistake on the limits. Thanks for pointing out. The integration by parts is a bit tricky because of the negative exponent but doable.

Comment: @GrantB. see the appendix for integration by parts